# ExcelDna not working on one machine

Tags: excel-dna

As far as I can detect all machines are the same that excelDna is being used on.

On one specific machine I tried to use the code I have created, and ran into an issue. Logically I thought this was odd and instead tried to add a sample file that comes with the download.

So now, I am trying Errors.xll/Errors.dna that come as a sample. The same error occurrs. Therefore to me there is an issue on this specific machine.

The error I am receiving is "a problem occurred while an add-in was being initialized (InitialIntegration failed). The add-in is built with ExcelDna and is being loaded from P:\xlDna\Distribution\Errors.xll"

Has anyone encountered this? Help needed to understand why this is happening as it seems quite opaque to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi what solved this for me was moving the xll and DNA to the users c:. Once located on the c: worked flawlessly.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.